# How is the Iota software updated on nodes?

Tags: iri-node, internet-of-things

Iota is intended to be deployed on IoT devices which have low resources: low CPU power, low storage, low bandwidth, and low energy.

How is it intended that the software is updated on nodes, given that the IRI is now 78.4MB and has been updated more than 12 times in the last year?

Take for example, automotive Telematics Control Units (TCUs). These will have 128MByte of flash and have a bandwidth budget of less than 50MByte/year. These will be challenged by such large updates.

Comment: Why would you assume the small IoT devices all run IRI?

Comment: I haven't assumed that. I've described a typical IoT device such as a gateway.

Comment: Gateways are usually mains-powered and not restricted in any of the ways you describe.

Comment: Just because they are mains powered, doesn't mean they aren't power, storage, bandwidth and energy constrained.

Comment: Usually those constrains are high enough to not be of concern. Gateways or IoT bridges like the Philips Hue Bridge will just update like any other connected device. 80MB & 12 times a year is not really an issue.

Comment: Take a TCU on a vehicle. They budget for around 50Mbyte/year of traffic. That's it. Look at many gateways. They have 128Mbytes of flash. That means you can't update and have a fallback image. If a node is battery powered then staying awake to download 78MBytes is going to cost you dear. These are real constraints that vendors work within.

Comment: Please integrate those information about what kind of gateways you're talking into the question with [edit]. You may ping me afterwards to remove all the comments.

Comment: The IOTA protocol is really just a transaction format. IRI is the suggested logic for choosing two transactions to approve, which gets updated from time to time (and maybe forever will) in a way that helps to improve the network. If a node fails to update this logic, they may be running a sub-optimal implementation, but no one else in the network would ever know. A node can choose two transactions to approve in any way that they like, and the recommended way has a random outcome anyway.